# how to watch less styles in a pod structure using ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-less

I'm facing an issue when moving my less files to a pod structure **outside the styles folder**.

I'm trying to put i.e:

```
pods/user/register/style.less

pods/components/app-login/styles
```

and import them from my **styles/app.less** file.

but so far it just **compiles for the first time**, but does **not watch for future changes**. I tried to create a symlink inside my styles folder to pods folder but sometimes works and sometimes breaks broccoli compilation so I declined.

Do you have a better workaround for this? For the moment im going back to the old structure.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use Less? The Ember core team may bet on Sass and incorporate https://github.com/ebryn/ember-component-css into the framework at some point in the future. Using that addon would provide you with everything you are after ...